# Routing: resource_path or resource_url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When you do map.resources on a model, it generates a bunch of routing helpers:

```
resource_path(@resource)
resource_url(@resource)
new_resource_url
etc.
```

What's the difference between using _path and _url? From what I've tried it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`foo_url` includes the domain and protocol. `foo_path` only outputs the relative path.

```
>> foo_url(:id => 1)
http://localhost:3000/foo/1

>> foo_path(:id => 1)
/foo/1
```

Most of the time, you want "_path" but you have the choice.

Comment: It's really just personal preference. One exception, is if you're building an RSS feed or something that needs the full url, then you should definitely use resource_url()

Comment: That's the reason why @jdl says "Most of the time".

Comment: When are these helpers generated? I am following the creators' primary tutorial to learn the framework and have just encountered a helper named `articles_path` but I'm not clear when it was created. Was it when I ran `rails generate model Article`?